# Port Mapping in Windows Server

Tags: ubuntu, windows-server-2008, internet

I have Windows Server 2003 and in WS virtual machine with Ubuntu server. Network: On host I have eth0 with real IP, virtual eth (192.168.0.1 - virtualbox interface), it's working in bridge mode with virtual eth0 on Ubuntu server. No NAT.

I need port mapping (syslog traffic) on Windows to Ubuntu Server. What should I do?
Administrate -> Route and remote access take error - ICS is ON. If I take it OFF - I haven't Internet on Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 0):

If the Ubuntu VM needs access to the Windows host, you need to ensure that they both have an IP that is reachable by the other.

This means either use IPs in separate networks that you route externally (or using RRAS), or use IPs in the same subnet (so no routing is needed.)